# incorrect address or soap action - Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, windows-server-2008

I have an application developed in VS2010 MVC, to install the application on the client IIS, it requires access to Web service application (asmx) on our server. I get this error "incorrect address or soap action" from Windows 2008 Server, I don't get the error from windows 7 or Vista?  Is there any specific setting required for the server?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite follow. the error comes from which piece when trying what specifically. Code?

Comment: The code is works well, the error is when I try to access the web service using Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I found the issue was proxy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was proxy settings.